# How to get body below header using relative positioning?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to create a page where the header is centered 70% of the window and a body 85% of the window. The header goes on top of the body, but I can't seem to accomplish this. When I add relative positioning to my #body div; the div seems to be positioned relative to the window (body) of the page instead of the header. How do I make it so the #body div is positioned relatively below the #header div so the body is going in the flow of the page? (I want all the elements inside #header to stay exactly where I positioned them).

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
        $resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");

        if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
        {
             while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $id = $rows["id"];
                $images = $rows["image"];
                $title = $rows["title"];

                if ($id <= 3)
                {


                    //Front page Div that contains all the header elements
                    echo "<div id=header>";
                    if ($id == 1)
                    {
                        //The front page div that contains the large image and the title
                        echo "<div id=largeDiv>";
                        echo "<img src=$images>";

                            //Div inside of largeImg div, that creates semi-transparent block for title
                            echo "<div id=largeTitle>";

                            //Main title of header
                            echo "<h2>$title</h2>";
                            echo "</div>";  //End of largeTitle div

                        echo "</div>";  //End of largeDiv

                    }

                    //Secondary div inside of #header that goes on the right side of #largeDiv
                    echo "<div id=smallDiv>";

                    if ($id == 2)
                    {
                        //Left image
                        echo "<img id=leftImg src=$images>";
                    }

                    if ($id == 3)
                    {
                        $text = $rows["text"];

                        //Right image
                        echo "<img id=rightImg src=$images>";

                        //Secondary div's title
                        echo "<h2>$title</h2>";

                        //Secondary div's text
                        echo "<p>$text</p>";
                    }

                        echo "</div>"; //End of smallDiv
                    echo "</div>"; //End of header
                }

                else
                {
                    echo "<div id=body>";

                    if ($id <= 13)
                    {
                        echo "<div id=left>";
                        echo "<img src=$images>";
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                    echo "</div>";

                }


            }
        }

    ?>
```

CSS

```
 /*BODY OF ENTIRE PAGE*/
body{
    position: relative;
}

/*HEADER OF PAGE. CONTAINS ALL HEADER ELEMENTS*/
#header{
    position: relative;
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 1.5% auto;
}

/*MAIN DIV OF HEADER*/
#largeDiv{
    position: absolute;
    width: 65%;
}

/*IMAGE OF THE MAIN DIV OF HEADER*/
#largeDiv img{
    width: 100%;
}

/*THE DIV INSIDE OF #LARGEDIV THAT IS A SEMI-TRANSPARENT BLOCK*/
#largeTitle{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    bottom: 1.5%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.4);
}

/*THE H2 TAG FOR THE MAIN TITLE OF THE HEADER, THIS IS INSIDE #LARGETITLE*/
#largeTitle h2{
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}

/*SECONDARY DIV OF HEADER, NEXT TO THE #LARGEDIV*/
#smallDiv{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    top: 0%;
    width: 32%;
    height: auto;
}

/*LEFT SMALL IMAGE OF HEADER*/
#leftImg{
    width: 45%;
    float: left;
}

/*RIGHT SMALL IMAGE OF HEADER*/
#rightImg {
    width: 45%;
    float: right;
}

/*THE TITLE OF THE SECONDARY DIV OF HEADER*/
#smallDiv h2{
    clear: both;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-top: 48%;
    color: cornflowerblue;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/*THE TEXT OF THE SECONDARY DIV OF HEADER*/
#smallDiv p{
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: -5%;
}

#body{

    position: relative;
    width: 85%;
}

#left{
    width: 28.33%;
}

#left img{  
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Sample dataset:

```
<div id=header><div id=largeDiv><img `src=http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnnnext/dam/assets/150429103538-bernie-sanders-gallery-photo-5-super-169.jpg><div id=largeTitle><h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Val hala mo sema serum.</h2></div></div><div id=smallDiv></div></div><div id=header><div id=smallDiv><img id=leftImg src=http://a4.files.biography.com/image/upload/c_fill,cs_srgb,dpr_1.0,g_face,h_300,q_80,w_300/MTE4MDAzNDEwMDU4NTc3NDIy.jpg></div></div><div id=header><div id=smallDiv><img id=rightImg` src=https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/602821590582038528/oobPhTxZ_400x400.png><h2>Prima disputando per ne, mea amet</h2><p>Ut usu soleat torquatos, vix iudico singulis constituto ut. In vim consul assueverit, ius no veniam voluptatum. Veritus vivendum</p></div></div><div id=body><div id=left><img src=http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg></div></div><div id=body><div id=left><img src=http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg></div></div><div id=body><div id=left><img src=http://newflowerwallpaper.com/download/flower-images-to-color-and-wallpapers/flower-images-to-color-and-wallpapers-16.jpg></div></div><div id=body><div id=left><img src=http://eskipaper.com/images/images-4.jpg></div></div>
```

Comment: Have you thought about using [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ?

Comment: Could you try giving us just the generated HTML with a sample dataset? I'm not sure the PHP code is so relevant to the question. (Ctrl-U in browser)

Comment: @Katana314 I have updated the question with the sample dataset.

Comment: Why not set up a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so that people can try out your code?

Answer (score 0):

`body` is a page construct and can't be repositioned, so the position style has no acutal effect.

What would be better is if your header content `#header` was inside another element such as a HTML5 style `header`, and perhaps `#body` inside a `main` container.

So, for example;

```
<body>
  <header>
    <div id="header">
       Header Content Here
    </div>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="body">
       <div id="left">
          Left Content
       </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

CSS

```
header {
   width: 100%;
}

#header{
   position: relative;
   width: 70%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 1.5% auto;
}

main {
   width: 100%;
}

#body {
   position: relative;
   width: 85%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

#left {
   width: 28.33%;
}
```

The above is an incomplete solution, but it's an example of how you look to structure your page.

An altnernative is to have a container (like `#container`) around all the content with the max width of the inner content.

Comment: Hmm, I tried implementing main and header, but it didn't work. I think the reason it's not working is because of scope. The header is only visible inside its respective if statement, and the body is only visible inside its respective if statement as well. When we try to position, the tags are always positioned relative to the body of the page instead of the flow. I don't understand how I can get the header and main tag outside of the if/else statements so the tags will be visible throughout the whole document